# Nothing happens after I submit the form

Tags: php, mysql

So I am building a simple question form that allows a user to submit a question and once the question is submitted it is sent to the database. I can't figure out why it isn't working. Here is my code, first one is the ask.html and the second is the ask.php.

```
<form action="ask.php" method="POST">
            Name: (not your real name)<br/>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            Question: <br/>
            <textarea name="question" cols="60" rows="10" id="question">
            </textarea>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
```

---

```
<?php

include('config.php');
include('open_connection.php');



if ((!$_POST[name]) || (!$_POST[question]))
    {
        header ("Location: ask.html");
        exit;
    }


    //Select database and table
    $db_name = "questionme";
    $table_name = "questions";

    //Insert data into database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name
    (name, question) VALUES
    ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[question]')";

    $result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Ask</title>
<head>
<body>

<h1>Question Submitted</h1>

<p><strong>Name:</strong>
<?php echo "$_POST[name]"; ?></p>

<p><strong>Question:</strong>
<?php echo "$_POST[question]"; ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly isn't working? What error msg do you see if any?

Comment: SQL injection much? Sanitize that input, please!

Comment: What, specifically, isn't working? Does the form not display correctly? When you submit does the redirect always/never/randomly occur? Is the SQL command returning an error? You need to explain exactly what you expect to see and what you are actually seeing.

Comment: Also, there is a reason for mysql_error()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is certainly generating warnings:

```
if ((!$_POST[name]) || (!$_POST[question]))
```

replace with

```
if (!isset($_POST[name]) || !isset($_POST[question]))
```

then **absolutely take into consideration what the other dudes answered**. On your INSERT:

```
('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[question]')";
```

would be better off as (they're also triggering warnings):

```
('{$_POST['name']}', '{$_POST['question']}')";
```

And on these

```
<?php echo "$_POST[name]"; ?></p>
...
<?php echo "$_POST[question]"; ?></p>
```

have them as

```
<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?></p>
...
<?php echo $_POST['question']; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your post variables with isset() and use quotes for the hashes you're checking:

```
if (!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['question']))
```

Also, never insert the values of your $_POST variables directly - do something like this instead:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$question = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you show_errors PHP configuration enabled?
Try placing some lines like 
echo "[1]";
echo "[2]"; 
etc to discover where your script terminates (debug a bit);
AND NEVER, NEVER USE _POST and _GET variables in SQL queries directly (use mysql_real_escape_string to escape their values)... or your script will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks!!!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using tables like $_POST['name'] in a string you have to wrap them with a {}

```
      $sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name
        (name, question) VALUES
        ('{$_POST[name]}', '{$_POST[question]}')";
<?php echo "{$_POST[name]}"; ?>
```

also